# Oracle GROUP BY and date precision

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by

I've got a table with two date fields : `BEGIN_DATE` and `END_DATE`

When I subtract these two fields, I get a number in days.
I want **this number in seconds** because the difference between these two fields is very tiny (~ 1s). 
So I proceed by doing :

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG((END_DATE-BEGIN_DATE)*3600*24),2) AS DELTA,
       TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS DEB, 
       TO_CHAR(END_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS FIN
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
         TO_CHAR(END_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

Here is the result (same precision with group by **minutes**) :
[image]

Well.
Then if I group the results **by hour** or **by day** :

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG((END_DATE-BEGIN_DATE)*3600*24),2) AS DELTA,
       TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') AS DEB, 
       TO_CHAR(END_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') AS FIN
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'), 
         TO_CHAR(END_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24');
```

I've got this result :
[image]

The `DELTA` precision is better and I can't understand why !

Could someone explain me ?

Comment: because average of 0 and 1 is 0.5?

Comment: Does the behavior continue if you remove columns Deb and Fin from your SELECT? Also what is the default value of your nls_date_format parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, don't go further, the problem is relatively simple.

Floating results are given by : SUM(DELTA) / COUNT(Grouped rows).

So if I've got 20 values at 2015-11-02 19.
9 of these values are equal to 1, remainder equals to 0.
We've got 9/20 = 0.45 which is absolutely logic.
I just verified it.

Thank you anyway for your time.